# How to debug (devtools) a website on iOS from Windows in 2021?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

All the options I found on the internet are outdated or don't work properly.

I need to debug a website on my iPhone, but I don't have a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered it. You should use this proxy:

https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy#installation